# JavaScript arrow function syntax. How does BOX as filter work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to learn JavaScript. I came across the following statement:

```
hero.powers = [...form.powers].filter(box => box.checked).map(box => box.value);
```

I'm wondering the "box" is apparently referring to a checkbox in the HTML page:

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this we can break it down:

`[...form.powers]`

- Use the spread syntax (`...`) to create an array from `form.powers` (a collection of DOM elements), in this case, it will be an array of checkbox DOM elements.

`.filter(box => box.checked)`

- This statement means go through all the elements in the array we created above, in this case, our elements are checkboxes, and keep only the checkboxes which are checked. As when we return `true` from within a `.filter` callback (the arrow function) we are telling it to keep the element in the array. Here `box` is refering to a given element in the array (as we go through/iterate over the array, `box` changes from element to element, or to be more precise, from checkbox to checkbox).

`.map(box => box.value);`

- This function will now loop/iterate over the filtered array (ie the array containing boxes which are only checked), and map/change each checkbox within it to the `value` of that checkbox. As `.map` changes the current iterated item to what it's callback returns. Again, in this case, `box` represents the current iterated item, which is a checkbox from our filtered array of checkboxes.

So overall:

`hero.powers = [...form.powers].filter(box => box.checked).map(box => box.value);`

Will set the `hero` objects `powers` attribute to be an array of the marked checkboxes' values.

See [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for more information on `.map()` and `.filter()`

Comment: HI. Just wondering about the "box". Where does this come from? Is it automatically referring to the checkboxes in the form?

Comment: yes, essentially. But when you do `form.powers` you essentially have a collection of these checkboxes. We then use `[...form.powers]` to convert it to an array so we can use `.map` `.filter` on it etc... If you look at `.filter` in general, it takes a `callback` which accepts an element from the array your looking at as its first argument. Eg: `[1, 2, 3].filter(num => num == 1)`. Here `num` simply refers to an element in the array `[1, 2, 3]`. The same idea can be applied to your checkboxes. Eg: `[checkbox_obj1, checkbox_obj2, checkbox_obj3].filter(box => box.checked)`, so in this case, `box`

Comment: is refering to the `checkbox` elements within the array

Comment: `box` is just a variable name that is passed into the callback function of the `filter` and `map` methods. `box` simply refers to the current element from the array that is being processed, but it could be named anything.

Comment: Have a read of these docs. They are pretty informative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thanks! got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The `form.powers` is probably a node list containing multiple HTML input elements. The spread syntax `[...form.powers]` changes the node list into an array, so you are able to map over it. Then you are filtering the newly created array from these inputs, which **are not** checked, so only these checked remains. Lastly, you are mapping over their values, so you will receive an array of strings, depends what values were written in these inputs.

In a brief:

- `[...form.powers]` - spread syntax changes a node list into an array
- `.filter(...)` - get rid of non-checked inputs
- `.map(...)` - get an array containing the values of checked inputs